# Reusable NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

Someone in that forum proposed me a code solution that worked great, but for my understanding, I would like to know what is the difference between the 2 blocks of code:

Block 1

```
NSMutableDictionary* step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Block 2

```
NSMutableDictionary* step_info = nil;
step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

It is may be also important to mention that step_info has to be filled and reuse repeatedly to load into another NSmutabledictionary.

Thank's for your help

Comment: I responsed to that other question. That is just my personal style to initialize variables to some known state. It is not required in this case. It might make more sense with more complex variables or structures.

This has less to do with iPhone programming and more with C programming and style.

Answer (score 2):

None. The compiler optimises `step_info = nil` away and you're left with the exact same code.

The following is another approach you could take:

```
NSMutableDictionary *step_info;
step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Comment: Ok, here my question again:
If I used that line code step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
many times at different places in my program, what does it do with my step_info NSMutabledicstionnary ?

Comment: @gpsdev: The previous `step_info` dictionaries are no longer accessible once overridden, filling up the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

Having `NSMutableDictionary* step_info;` first allows you to use `step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` later in the same block of code.

If you wish to assign a value to step_info in multiple methods, it'd be better if you add `NSMutableDictionary* step_info` in the `@interface` section of the header file.

That way you can use `step_info = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` in any method in your implementation file, then assign values and keys this way: `[step_info setValue: value forKey: key];`